# how to use multiple authentication in aws amplify using cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

we are using cognito authentication in aws amplify which takes the username(email) and password for login.
how can a custom authentication be added along with the existing to support OTP based login.
have found many solution which provide the custom authentication OTP based login, but it should also support the existing username and password login as well.